# Meteor: how to store assets (eg in /public) that are hot-refreshed and secured

Tags: android, ios, meteor

We are building a Meteor app that will be deployed to the app stores and online.
We need to store assets that will be auto-refreshed with Meteor (eg via hot-code-push), including in the app store versions.
The normal approach would be to put the assets into /public directory.
However, this means that the assets are all insecure and can be accessed and downloaded directly by anyone.

How can we make the assets in a Meteor app:

1. available to our app (in this case they are audio files that the app will play)
2. refresh when the app code updates, without requiring a new download from the app store
3. secure, so that only the app can access them, not outside bandits?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using something like S3 or CloudFront with [signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) or [signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) will be a lot more robust than rolling your own solution.

That being said, if you want to implement this yourself you could combine the security ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734110/authentication-on-server-side-routes-in-meteor) with my answer to [how to serve files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565991/how-to-serve-a-file-using-iron-router-or-meteor-itself).

The answer really depends on how you want to store your files.