# meteor posts by current user

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

I am following the tutorial on the simple `posts` app and make it to work(that you put in your `name` and `message` then `submit`, and `meteor` will update it to `messages template`). Now I want to extend it to have user sign in and messages will only show the `posts` by the `current user`. I got the `sign in` to work but not sure how to change the message code so that it work something like this:

```
{{#if currentuser}}
   {{#each messages}}
        {{posts by currentuser}}
    {{/each}}  
{{/if}}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the **correct** approach to this is to do this **server side**.

What you **want** to do is return only the *posts* data for the `current user` who is logged in, because otherwise you are proposing to get **all** the posts and *filter* them in your client. That is going to be slow, and why return results that you do not need?

One of the strengths of Meteor as a development platform is that it *abstracts* a lot of the differences between *client* and *server* side code. But **this** is an area where you should not be relying on the general abstraction.

This question should show you the ropes of how to filter out your **server** query to do this:

[How to get Meteor.user() to return on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532316/how-to-get-meteor-user-to-return-on-the-server-side)

We could offer more help. But you didn't provide that part that we need in your question. If you have trouble working this out, then perhaps another question then?