# How to filter a list per Session on Meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I am working a Ticket System on Meteor. And I am trying to make a dashboard with the amount of tickets per status (# Open, # In Progress and # Closed). However I have to filter it out per role [Client and Administrator]. **Screenshot**: http://screencast.com/t/1IteIss0

Let's say an example:

- I am a client and I should only see tickets that I have created.
- And I am an administrator but I have to be able to see all tickets created for all clients.

Then I have the following code created. However I would like your help in order to how can I filter the tickets per role.

```
Client Site

Template.dashboard.onCreated(function(){
   this.subscribe('getStatus');
});

Template.dashboard.helpers({
   tickets: function() {
     return Status.find({});
}
});

Server Site

Meteor.publish("getStatus", function(args) {
var sub = this;

var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;

var pipeline = [
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$status", 
        "count": { "$sum": 1}
    }}
];

db.collection("Tickets").aggregate(        
    pipeline,
    // Need to wrap the callback so it gets called in a Fiber.
    Meteor.bindEnvironment(
        function(err, result) {
            // Add each of the results to the subscription.
            _.each(result, function(e) {
                // Generate a random disposable id for aggregated documents
                sub.added("Status", Random.id(), {
                    "Status": e._id,
                    "value": e.count
                });
            });
            sub.ready();
        },
        function(error) {
            Meteor._debug( "Error doing aggregation: " + error);
        }
    )
);
});
```

I really appreciate all your help on this matter.

If you have any question just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It should be done on publication level.
You can check there userid and by using [How to get Meteor.user() to return on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532316/how-to-get-meteor-user-to-return-on-the-server-side)
there is also role package that has helpful ideas
https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I am using roles. But can I filter the method getStatus on server side per role? where the aggregate function can work as expected.

Comment: Gova what's the problem? When you know what kind of role the user you can manipulate filters on mongo queries

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. And I would like to know then how can I manipulate filters on mongo per role? do you have any example? In this case I would like to create two pipeline one for client and the other one for administrator

Comment: Frankly I don't get the issue you have. You just filter fields. Look at the example https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/issues/120 made by aldeed commented on Jan 8. It shows how it's done. I hope it will clarify the problem.